# Custom code in designer.vb file goes away when making edits in design mode

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, controls, designer

I have a form named "form1" in vb.net. This form has many controls. I opened the form1.designer.vb file and put in an if else expression such as:

If getLanguage() = "en" then label1.text = "Good Morning" Else label1.Text = "Bonjour"

This works perfectly fine in runtime.

If I open the Form1.vb [Design] page in design, and make any changes, the code above disappears.

Is there a way I can keep any code I put in the designer page?
I don't want to put them in the load event in the form1.vb file.

Comment: That's normal... .designer.vb (or .cs) shouldn't be edited by hand. You can put your special code in the class' constructor.

Comment: You see in the designer.vb file where it has a comment `'Do not modify it using the code editor.`? They mean it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate this code :

```
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
```

Then add a line :

```
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.MakeComponentsChanges()
    End Sub
```

Then create the method in form1.vb or another Partial Class copy of your creation :

```
    Private Sub MakeComponentsChanges()
        If getLanguage() = "en" then
            label1.text = "Good Morning"
        Else
            label1.Text = "Bonjour"
        End If
    End Sub
```

Don't touch the form1.designer.vb (.cs)

---

And as stated in other answers, better use `.Localizable` Property in the IDE and change it from `False` to `True`. Then you'll gain access to several default languages. You don't have to bother writing code.

- Select ONE language to start with : `English` for example.
- Then edit each one of your controls Text : write "Hello" in a button, "Good Morning" in a Label, "Because I'm Happy" in a MenuItem etc.
- Then change the language again, select `French`.
- Then edit again each control and write "Bonjour", "Je vous souhaite un bon matin", "Parceque je suis de bonne humeur".... **YES** you've lost the previous text but **have faith** !
- Compile your project without launching it, and you'll see the IDE has created **two new files** : `Form1.en.resx` and `Form1.fr.resx` (or so) along with `Form1.vb` and `Form1.Designer.vb`. Don't edit them !

If you open the en.resx or fr.resx, you'll see that the edits you've made are **in there**. Those files are used to store inbuilt Lang-related ressources for your form. That's flatly called Globalization.

Then locate again the constructor of your Form.

```
    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        'Me.MakeComponentsChanges()
        ' Now you know about some Globalization, 
        ' you may get rid of that Method.

        ' Add two variables :
        Dim OriginalCulture As CultureInfo
        Dim CurrentOSCulture As CultureInfo

        ' Initialize them
        OriginalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        CurrentOSCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

        ' Do this test :
        Try
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CurrentOSCulture ' may fail
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CurrentOSCulture ' may fail
            ' Attempt to match the current Thread culture to the Operating System one.
        Catch CurrentException As Exception
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = OriginalCulture
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = OriginalCulture
            ' If it fails, revert back to default as defined in your IDE
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Don't forget to add on top of your Class declaration those two namespaces :

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Threading
```

And voilà ! I know I said you don't have to bother writing code, but the bits above in the constructor are enough to handle the selection of a language. *Plus besoin de taper du code superflu après ça.*

Comment: Thanks just the answer I was looking for... It is very useful to learn about Localizable. However I still need to put my own code after the InitializeComponent since sometimes the user gets to change the RightToLeft property, and on slow computer and in forms with a lot of controls you get flicker so this solves.. thanks everyone else

Answer (score 2):

For your example maybe better will be using property of the form

```
.Localizable = true
.Language = Default(French)/English/or others
```

Visual Studio create two files of one class(which is your form) - [Partial Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514141.aspx)
So it is doesn't matter in which file you write your code.
Only visual studio use `designer.vb` file for generating form changes you made by designer

Code from `designer.vb` contain method `InitializeComponent` which executed in the constructor.
Create your own method and call it right after `InitializeComponent` in constructor.
Or create third file for your code if you don't want put in the `yourform.vb`

File `yourForm.MyDesigner.vb`

```vb
'Using Keyword Partial not necessary anymore,  
'because it is used in the `yourForm.Designer.vb` 
Public Class yourForm

    Public Sub Changelabel()
        If getLanguage() = "en" Then 
            label1.text = "Good Morning" 
        Else 
            label1.Text = "Bonjour"
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for your answer but I went with #fsintegral because it was explained more

Answer (score 1):

designer.vb files are created automatically by Visual Studio. Every time you edit the design of the form, the file is re-written.
Now, why you don't want to have that code on Load? The load event or the constructor (as already stated) are the right places where to put any initialization you need.

Comment: Because sometimes I wanna change the righttoleft property so in your way makes the change after loading and when there are a lot of controls and on an old computer that would look annoying and slow