# Display controls in Designer VB.Net 2013

Tags: vb.net, designer

I have a set of controls which are added dynamically to a panel. The number of controls depends on which tab a user selects from TabPage control, which is embedded in a form.

At the moment, the controls don't appear in Designer, but appear during execution.

I managed to display controls for other forms which are not dynamic by moving the non-design code to the vb file, but how can I display the other ones?

Comment: Please fix your question title, unless you know something I don't about versions.  Maybe 2023 is the subscription version of VS.  :)

Comment: @dbasnett mikimr is obviously from the future and using the 2023 version of VB.NET :]

Comment: First, get yourself a vintage DeLorean...

Comment: _The number of controls depends on which tab a user selects from TabPage control_ - so why not add controls in the designer for every tabpage

Answer (score 0):

The only answer that I know of is to add your code in the .Designer.vb file of the Form.

**BUT**! I strongly advise you to avoid that if you are not sure how it works! Custom code in the .Designer. files can break your form design and project with possible random crashes.

Also, your code can be changed and removed by the Visual Studio designer:
[Custom code in designer.vb file goes away when making edits in design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001210/custom-code-in-designer-vb-file-goes-away-when-making-edits-in-design-mode)

Instead, you can make the panels into custom user controls and add those to the tabs.

Comment: All manually added code to the designer.vb will be erased after any change in the designer.